# Figuring out how storage is configured to Hyper-V cluster

Tags: hyper-v, storage-area-network, direct-attached-storage

I am presented with a Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V cluster (2 nodes) and the nodes are connected to an HP MSA 2040 storage (SAN?) with direct fiber connection.

I am trying to figure out how the connection to the storage is configured but I don't get it because it looks to me like the fiber NICs are disabled. Still, on the physical side of things I can see that it's only a direct fiber cable running to the storage device.

[image: Network interfaces]

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I have little to no experience with external storage configurations (except from standard Windows storage configurations).

Comment: Which EXACT model of 2040 do you have, they made a few variants

Comment: I have the following information:
- HP MSA 2040 SAN Controller
- Enclosure Model SPS-CHASSIS
- Version GL220P009 - you need anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell command `Get-InitiatorPort`. This should tell you what kind of connection you have to your storage (ISCSI / FC) as well as the hardware IDs and relevant ports.

From there you can check Disk Management and Device Manager in administrative tools to double check everything.

Edit: It seems you'd like a full map of your storage.

The Get-InitiatorPort command will list the WWNs of the FC interfaces, you can match these to the entries in the hosts section of the MSA management utility. This will show you which ports connect where and what LUNs they are using to map volumes on the MSA to the hosts. You can then check the LUN numbers in Disk management by right clicking on the disks and viewing the properties.

There's a manual for the MSA2040 on [the HP website](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c05075467), there's also a section on [configuring LUNs](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c05075467#N10E5B) that may help

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I ran the Powershell command and I see 4 Fibre Channel entries and one iSCSI entry. In Device Manager & in Disk Management I see several disk drives called "HP MSA 2040 SAN SCSCI Disk Device". It's good to know & see these things but I need to know how it was configured. I need to be able to troubleshoot or rebuild it in case there is an issue.

Comment: I also don't understand how the Fibre NICs can be set to disabled while it looks like they are being used? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I also see that the disks are CSVFS

Comment: Your two disabled NICs are the HP Flex 10GB network adapters (10gb copper, not fibre). You could also check ISCSI initiator in administrative tools as well as MPIO if you're dual attaching your storage. CSVFS just means that the storage is shared between nodes, it doesn't rely on the storage implementation underneath. It's possible to build CSVFS volumes on top of SAS/FC/ISCSI

Comment: I checked the ILO of one of the servers and I see the following in the inventory:

HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 533FLR-T Adapter => offline (so that's indeed ethernet - thanks) AND secondly:
HP SN1000Q 16Gb 2P FC HBA => Status OK

Comment: The iSCSI initiator is empty.

Comment: If you've only got fibre running to your MSA, the FC HBA will be the card you're trying to find, FC HBA interfaces won't show in the network interfaces list as they're a different kind of interface altogether! You can probably ignore the 533FLR-T if it's disabled, no traffic will be passing on those interfaces.

Comment: I don't find anything related to MPIO

Comment: Ok, it's the FC HBA. Now I need to find something about that in Windows Server I guess?

Comment: The Get-InitiatorPort command will list the WWNs of the FC interfaces, you can match these to the entries in the hosts section of the MSA management utility, this will show you which ports connect where and what LUNs they are using to map volumes on the MSA to the hosts. You can then check the LUN numbers in Disk management by right clicking on the disks and viewing the properties. that should give you a full map of your storage.

Comment: That's great info! I can see a link there indeed between port address and the hosts ID in the MSA utility. I don't see any mappings though. Would you know where I could find a guide on such a configuration?

Comment: No problem, see updated answer!

Comment: Many thanks, I will go through that and see if I can finally grasp the full picture. Thanks again for your great help!